# (Help!) erased lsb-release when installing Intel graphics driver

Tags: lsb-release

I erased lsb-release when installing Intel graphics driver. i typed( sudo rm /etc/lsb-release /etc/lsb-release.backup ) now i can't restore the file or reinstall it from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the contents of my lsb-release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
```

Different Ubuntu releases will obviously have different values there.

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 14.04.2, but i'll try if this works

Comment: Then you should modify the values accordingly.  `14.04`, `trusty`, and `"Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"`

Comment: i think it worked, but how can i be sure?

Comment: It's a fairly uncomplicated file, so I think it'll probably be fine, but you can test it with the command `lsb_release --all`.  It should show all four pieces of information and maybe a notice about no LSB modules.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful feel free to vote for it or select it as the chosen answer.